# Why is a "cowardly" person referred to as "yellow"?

Tags: etymology

**Yellow** not only designates a kind of color, but also describes **cowardice**. But why? Where does the reference come from?

*OED* (paywalled) notes, about sense [3b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231534?rskey=J8kkgF&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) of 'yellow' ["*colloquial* (originally *U.S.*). Lacking in courage; faint-hearted; cowardly", updated January, 2018], that

> …the origin of the specific association of the colour with cowardice, which seems to have arisen in American contexts in the later 19th cent., is unclear.

Comment: [Sense of "cowardly" is of unknown origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yellow)

Comment: You'll find lots of speculation/ history about its origins at http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/yellow-belly.html

Comment: I am vaguely recalling once reading an account of some military situation where soldiers who were somehow stained yellow would be presumed to have been avoiding the front lines.  But I can't recall what the supposed mechanism was that accomplished this staining.

Comment: @HotLicks, well, one could pee oneself in fear.

Comment: @HemiPoweredDrone - That's what I thought of, as well.  It works better as a metaphor rather than literal description, though, I expect it would be easier to smell the difference rather than see the color (as opposed to just looking wet).

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/yellow-belly.html suggests it originates with an account of a military skirmish in Texas, where the Texas army were going to attack the mexican army after the mexicans crossed the Colorado. It remains unclear why they were referred to as yellow bellies or quite where the cowardice comes in.

Comment: Maybe the expression 'yellow' has something to do with this : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yellow_union#English. Besides, the French call strikebreakers 'des jaunes' to denounce their cowardice and complete submission to the boss.